# Calling options/arguments of gdal_translate in Python

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate

I want to port a `gdal_translate` into Python. It is about translating a GeoTIFF into a Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG). I do not know how to insert the option `-of` and its input.

Here's is the equivalent CLI for that:

```
gdal_translate input.tif output_cog.tif -of COG -co COMPRESS=LZW
```

My current Python Code:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open('input.tif')
ds = gdal.Translate('output.tif', ds, options=["COMPRESS=LZW"])
```

How can I insert the input/argument `-of COG` into the Python code?

I got the code here: https://www.cogeo.org/developers-guide.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add all your parameters as a string (like in the command line version of gdal_translate):

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Translate('output.tif', 'input.tif', options="-of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW")
```

I used GTiff format because there is no COG driver in my gdal 3.0.4 version. I used the name of the input instead loading into ds and overwriting with the output of gdal.Translate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and tip. I will be checking my work next time.